# How to submit a document to DSpace with SWORD 2.0?

Tags: curl, dspace

I am trying to submit a deposit to the demo DSpace instance at http://demo.dspace.org/, using the SWORD 2.0 interface. All my attempts result in various HTTP 500 errors.

It would be great if anyone could provide a curl one-liner to deposit a simple PDF file to this DSpace instance.

Here is my latest attempt (where `article.pdf` is a random PDF file):

```
curl -u dspacedemo+submit@gmail.com:dspace http://demo.dspace.org/swordv2/collection/10673/2 -X POST -d @article.pdf -H "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=article.pdf"
```

which raises the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFWriterFImpl.setBaseWriterClassName(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like something has gone wrong in the deployment of the DSpace demo instance. You should report this using the [official DSpace issue tracker](https://jira.duraspace.org/projects/DS/issues).

Your curl command looks OK though you may wish to include the packaging header (eg `-H "Packaging: http://purl.org/net/sword/package/Binary"`). I also don't remember whether Swordv2 will let you deposit just a file as a new DSpace item or whether you need to supply some minimal metadata (eg title) in this scenario (edit, no, you should be fine according to [the Sword v2 specs](https://swordapp.github.io/SWORDv2-Profile/SWORDProfile.html#protocoloperations_creatingresource_binary)).

Have you tried adding `-H "X-Verbose: true"` for additional error messages? But really this does look like a deployment problem.

Comment: Yes I aim to deposit some metadata as well, but I was trying to narrow down the problem. I'll report the issue then.